# How to get url for recipient preview to sign in docusign?

Tags: docusignapi

i hit this url with POST method [https://demo.docusign.net/restapi/v2.1/accounts/{accId}/envelopes/{envId}/views/recipient_preview](https://demo.docusign.net/restapi/v2.1/accounts/%7BaccId%7D/envelopes/%7BenvId%7D/views/recipient_preview) but return error Error while requesting server, received a non successful HTTP code [400] with response Body:  O:8:"stdClass":2:{s:9:"errorCode";s:20:"INVALID_REQUEST_BODY";s:7:"

i can get url for recipient preview without checking my email

Answer (score 0):

You need JSON in the body that has two things:

```
{"recipientId":"{{RECIPIENT_ID}}","returnUrl":"{{YOUR_URL}}"}
```

To find the **recipientId** you will need to make another API call to get the envelope and all its recipients.

Comment: i can get the url, but its need to sign to docusign account for add signature

Comment: I don't understand what you mean